# jQuery for html table to change cell contents base on other cell values

Tags: jquery, forms, html-table

I have a table similar to this, but with many rows:

```
<table width=400px id=mytable>
 <tr>
  <td>test one</td>
  <td>yes</td>
  <td>success</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>test two</td>
  <td>yes</td>
  <td>none</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

The values are populated by a database dynamically. If the 2nd td in each row has a value of yes, how can I change the value of the 3rd td to be say "in progress"? The value is yes as the user has submitted a test but the test is in progress and the value of td3 is none until the database populates td3.

I have this bit of jquery I have used, however it just searches and replaces text based on a cell only, not say the next cell.

```
$(function() {
    $('#mytable td').each(function() {
        var html = $(this).html();
        $(this).html(
        html.replace(/0/,'<b>success</b>')
             .replace(/1/,'<b>failed</b>')
        );
    });
});
```

I've also been playing with this code, but this doesn't fit what I want to do as it only updates certain TDs based on the .eq(x) placement.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mytable').find('td').eq(4).text('changeme');
});
```

My table could has around 20 rows and I would like to do this for every 2nd td in my table

Ideally I would like a throbber but that should be possible once I can interpret the 2nd td values.

Comment: It looks like you already know what you're doing. Incorporate `if` statements with `$('#mytable').find('td').eq(4).text('changeme');` to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will go through the td's, see if a cell has a value 'none' and if yes, it sets the value of next cell to 'in progress':

```
$(function() {
    $('#mytable td').each(function() {
        var html = $(this).html();
        if (html == "none")
            $(this).next().html("in progress");
        });
});
```

Updated code as per comment below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('td').each(function() {
        if ($(this).html() == "yes" && $(this).next().html() == "none") {
            $(this).next().html("in progress");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Damn it, I didn't ask my question right! Your solution does indeed answer my question, but my scenario doesn't play out like my question. So in fact, the cell td2 will be yes and td3 will be none. td3 will get updated when the test result comes in. Whilst td2 is yes and td3 is none, I want to change the value of td3 to 'in progress'. But when td3 gets updated, I want to show to database values, success or failed. Can you code be changed to do a ... if (html == "yes") and $(this).next == none) ...?

Comment: I have updated the code. I hope I understood you correctly :) JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/W4jSu/1/

Comment: i've just tried to implement your solution but have hit a few problems. Maybe some other jquery stuff is breaking it. I am using the same code in my webpage jsfiddle.net/W4jSu/18 ?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the delay. Yes this is perfect and is now up and running in my website - Works a treat. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table tr').each(function(){
    $('td:eq(1):contains(yes)', this).next().text('in progress')
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CYdVs/

Comment: I realized after these solutions that I didn't ask my question right, so I've updated my question..

Comment: @Oli Just replace none with yes.

Comment: cool - yeah. these answers have helped me understand that i can change and play with the jquery easily.. thanks for your help

Comment: @Oli Yes, jQuery has simplified working with the DOM massively. You can read the api and easily do whatever that can be done.

Comment: yeah I've just come up with an blinding solution, based on changing my django app slightly. I have jquery now updating the page with values of in progress and images which goes to completed and success | failure when the test value comes in. V happy. Thanks for you answer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#mytable td').each(function() {
    var html = $(this).html();
    if(html === 'none'){
        $(this).next('td').text('in progress');
}
});
```

See working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbkXk/)

Comment: I realized after these solutions that I didn't ask my question right, so I've updated my question..

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/mgjZG/)

```
$(function() {
    var secondCells = $('tr').find('td:eq(1)');
    console.log(secondCells)
    $.each(secondCells, function(i) {
        if( $(this).text() == 'none'){
            console.log($(this).next())
           $(this).next().text('Processing..');
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: great - thanks. I looked at this and it helped me come up with my solution. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

This example will go through every second td in row and if value is 'none' it replace next cell to 'in progress':

```
$("#mytable td:nth-child(2)").each(function(index, elem)
{
    if($(elem).html() === "none")
    {
        $(elem).next().html("in progress")
    }
});​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/752NU/)

Comment: I realized after these solutions that I didn't ask my question right, so I've updated my question..

Answer (score -1):

you can run a loop with each(), run a counter with it and check each time if the counter is even or odd.

[CSS-Tricks.com : Check if even or odd](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/check-if-number-is-evenodd/)

There is for sure a better way to do it, though.